# helloword solj programe goves me an exception 'bad request'

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I try to index this data in solr from my java application.

The problem is that it gives me this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Bad Request

request: http://localhost:8983/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:436)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:55)
    at com.gismo.ReadFromSolr.main(ReadFromSolr.java:47)
```

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, SQLException, IOException 
        { String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/db";

     CommonsHttpSolrServer solrServer = new
                 CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

                         SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
                         doc1.addField( "pk_id", "id1");
                         doc1.addField("doc_type", "content");
                         doc1.addField( "id", "1");
                         doc1.addField( "content_text", "hello world" );

                         Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new
                         ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
                         docs.add(doc1);
                         solrServer.add(docs);
                         solrServer.commit(); 
    }
```

So I've got one more questions

**1. Do i need to declarethis fields somewhere before indexing : for example in solr 
C:\solr-4.1.0\example\solr\collection1\conf\schema.xml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to make sure those four fields you are referencing in your `SolrInputDocument` are declared in the `<fields>` section of your schema.xml. Please reference [SchemaXml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) as needed.

Also, please note that `CommonsHttpSolrServer` has been deprecated favor of [HttpSolrServer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#HttpSolrServer), so I would recommend using that class.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response - but as I'm new to solr - I suppose that i shpould add teh field in this folder - ../example/solr/collection1/conf or am I wrong

Comment: I forgot to thank you - now everything is all right with indexing